# Can the CPS-styled `call/cc` be written in terms of a hypothetical non-CPS-styled `cc'`?

Tags: ruby, haskell, scheme, continuations, continuation-passing

In a language which supports continuation, e.g. Scheme, Ruby, and Haskell, suppose there is a function `cc'` which takes no argument and return the current continuation, so that the caller that obtains a continuation by calling `cc'` can then invoke the continuation anywhere and as often as it likes.

`cc'` can be written in terms of the CPS-styled `call/cc`, by passing an identity function as an argument to `call/cc`.

Conversely, can the CPS-styled `call/cc` be written in terms of the non-CPS-styled `cc'`?

Comment: `call/cc(f) = f(cc)`?

Comment: @rampion That is intuitive, but wrong (AFAICS). It would cause `g(call/cc(f)) = g(f(cc)) = call/cc(g . f)`, where the last `.` denotes function composition, and this is clearly not what we want. The point is that, intuitively, `f` should receive the continuation "without `f` itself", when `f(cc)` includes `f` in the continuation.

Comment: Haskell *doesn't* natively support continuations. Delimited continuations can be implemented in the language (e.g., the `ContT r` monad transformer and various CPSish things like `Codensity`), but there is no support whatsoever for undelimited continuations like Scheme has.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt (warning: I am an inexperienced schemer). Let `get-cc` be the function returning the current continuation.

```lisp
(define (get-cc)
  (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (k) k)))
```

Then, we can define:

```lisp
(define (callCC f)
  (let ((w (get-cc)))
    (if (pair? w)
      (car w)
      (f (lambda (x) (w (cons x '())))))))
```

The first time this function is called, `w` is bound to the current continuation. So, `(pair? w)` is false, and we call `f` with continuation `(lambda (x) (w (cons x '()))`.

When `w` is called though `f` (with argument `(cons x '())`), then the body of the `let` is entered again, where `w` is now bound to `(cons x '())`.
Now, `(pair? w)` is true, and we can return `(car w)` which is `x`.

The pair wrapper is used so as to distinguish what is "the continuation for `f`" from "the result *from* `f`", so to speak.

A quick test shows this to be working, but I'm not completely confident of its correctness.

You probably noticed that `w` is bound to values of different types. That is why I resorted to an untyped language like Scheme instead of Haskell.